# WPF multiple windows, change combobox affects both bindings

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a listbox which lists user details and on selection opens that user detail in a new instance of the user detail window

```
using UserDetailWin udw = new UserDetailWindow(); 
udw.show();
```

Comboboxes in the window are populated by a shared CollectionViewSource and SelectedValue is done through TwoWay binding.

The problem is when I have more than one UserDetailWin open and change the combobox selection in one all the others get that selected id.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Kier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. If you understand object references, then it should be easy to figure out by yourself.

To fix this, you should create new instance of `CollectionViewSource` for each combo box.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same DataContext for all opened windows. Make selected user DataContext of new window and bind all variables directly (by setting DataContext property of UserDetailWin).